# C# Unreachable Code Detected

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I've been messing around for over an hour now. I still don't know how to solve it even reading the Stackoverflow solution. The program works with the first username and password (test & password), when I typed in the second username and password (aaa & 123) it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    String[] username = { "test", "aaa" };
    String[] password = { "password", "123" };

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < username.Length; i++) // <------- Unreachable Code
            {
                if ((txtUsername.Text.Trim() == username[i]) && (txtPassword.Text.Trim() == password[i]))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful. Welcome!", "Login Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                    Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                    frm3.Visible = true;
                    frm3.Activate();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid input. Do you want to try again?", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand); break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("System Error! Please try again!", "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont need to break in `if` statement.

Comment: Please don't do `catch(Exception x)`. It's bad. Just let the exceptions bubble up otherwise you're hiding errors. In this case, for example, any errors in `Form3` could be handled here. That's bad. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `break` word in both `if-else` branches. Remove `break` from else. But you will get message boxes on every loop. So you need to modify your code: move message box outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have logical flow control issues inside of your code.  As a result, you need to move the MessageBox firing outside of your loop.

If you modify your code to use lists instead of arrays and include a bit of LINQ, you can move away from a loop altogether, as well as you can benefit from less nesting.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    List<string> username = new List<string>{ "test", "aaa" };
    List<string> password = new List<string>{ "password", "123" };

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text.Length > 0 && txtPassword.Text.Length > 0 
                && username.Any(x => x == txtUsername.Text.Trim())
                && password.Any(x => x == txtPassword.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Login Successful. Welcome!", 
                    "Login Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                frm3.Visible = true;
                frm3.Activate();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "You have entered an invalid input. Do you want to try again?", 
                     "Invalid Input", 
                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "System Error! Please try again!", "System Error", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
}
```